# About Husky UGV Connection

Tags: ros2, control, husky

Somehow a Husky UGV came into the lab without any sensors or onboard PC.
Fortunately, there is a laptop with ROS2 Humble installed and a PS4 controller.

Q1. What do I need to do to act as an Onboard PC connecting a laptop with ROS2 Humble installed between the robot and the controller?

Q2. What do I do to connect a laptop and a robot, then connect a PS4 controller for wireless control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Russ76 that you should get in touch with clearpath about this, but I would point out that Clearpath does a pretty good job of documenting their platforms and open-sourcing code. For example, here's [code for the Husky](https://github.com/husky/husky) on GitHub, and [here's the user manual](https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/robots/outdoor_robots/husky/user_manual_husky/).

I would contact clearpath first to make sure they've given you everything you ordered, but if they have: I would install ROS to some laptop or SBC, then load the Husky packages onto that device (just like any other ROS package).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to call Clearpath Robotics in Canada. The Husky is a robot of theirs. They have a proprietary software system.

https://clearpathrobotics.com/